# Cosa significa "volta" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Gli occhiali d'oro*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Con la tecnica, quasi, di un cronista sportivo della radio, riferiva ad esempio che «gli sposini», alzatisi d'un tratto dalle sedie a sdraio, stavano dirigendosi alla **volta** del più vicino moscone: evidentemente il giovanotto aveva espreso il desiderio di tuffarsi al largo, e il «signor dottore», per non rimaner solo, «in palpiti», ad attenderne il ritorno, aveva ottenuto di accompagnarlo.

Potreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "volta" in questo brano? 
Ho cercato questo termine in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le tante accezioni che ho trovato, non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo contesto ***alla volta*** significa verso:

> Stavano dirigendosi ***verso*** il più vicino moscone

Da Treccani per [volta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volta1/)

> 3. estens. e fig. a. La direzione in cui ci si volge andando, soprattutto nell’espressione alla v. di ..., che introduce un
>      complemento indicante la persona o il luogo verso cui ci si dirige:
>      *sono partiti alla v. di Firenze; venivano alla nostra volta.*