# Significato di "volta" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto la frase seguente:

> Ahimè, non ero ancor sceso
>   a piè del mio picco, che scorsi un pattuglione il quale, senza peraltro avermi veduto, veniva dritto alla mia **volta**.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "alla mia volta" che appare in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo "volta" in alcuni dizionari, ma ci sono tantissime accezioni che non sono sicura di aver capito. Significa che il pattuglione veniva dritto nella stessa direzione in cui stava camminando l'io narrante?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cosa significa "volta" in questo contesto?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/cosa-significa-volta-in-questo-contesto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esatto, significa che la pattuglia si stava dirigendo verso la direzione di chi sta narrando.

Prendendo la definizione della [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volta1/)

> 3. estens. e fig. a. La direzione in cui ci si volge andando, soprattutto nell’espressione *alla v. di* ..., che introduce un
>      complemento indicante la persona o il luogo verso cui ci si dirige:
>      *sono partiti alla v. di Firenze; venivano alla nostra volta.*